# How to fix room if i can see light coming through from attic

Tags: shingles

We had strong winds in Boston and I just happened to go in the attic and I saw that there's direct light coming through 2 spots right in the middle of the roof. [image]

Looks like the wind blew off the middle shingles. How should I go about reparing this? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Whoa! That's significant damage and there may be other damage as well - some not so obvious. You really need someone who knows what they're doing on-site to assess the amount of damage and recommend what repairs are needed. In the meantime you might want to tarp that area.

Comment: Depends on the roof construction, but there may be coping stones missing. You're going to have to get to it from the outside to assess the damage [& to fix it] Nothing you can do from the inside.

Comment: The ridge cap is missing, as pointed out by HoneyDo, there could be more damage around the openings. You need a roofer to perform the repair ASAP, otherwise, more roofing material could be gone after the next strong wind event.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that needs to be resolved quickly before you get a lot of water damage. I would contact the home insurance company and see what they recommend, more than likely they will be paying the bill. The whole roof can be checked for additional damage and repaired at the same time.  Also your home insurance probably will pay for a contractor to come out and make emergency repairs to protect the remaining property. Best call NOW.

Comment: Tell the insurance company it just happened. They pay for things that happen quickly. They do NOT pay for things that happen over a period of time. They call that maintenance and figure you should have fixed it.